# Which spring-security version is compatible with Spring 5.2.8.RELEASE?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

I have an existing spring mvc project where I'm using spring 4.3.23.RELEASE version with spring security 4.2.13.RELEASE.
Now I want to upgrade the spring version 5.2.8.RELEASE. I don't identify which spring-security version is compatible with Spring 5.2.8.RELEASE version?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the Spring Security Reference manual will answer this.  For example, the manual for the [Spring Security 5.2.5 RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/getting.html) says:

> Spring Security builds against Spring Framework 5.2.6.RELEASE but should generally work with any newer version of Spring Framework 5.x.

(The next release of Spring Security after 5.2.5 is 5.3.0.)

So I would *expect* Spring Security 5.2.5 would work with Spring Framework 5.2.8.

The Spring Security Reference manual also advises you to use "spring-framework-bom" to simplify dependency management.  The idea is that you select a specific "bom" version and that gives you a set of compatible versions numbers for any of the Spring components that you use.

Answer (score 1):

Spring documentation is the best source, but in case you are still unclear then the following approach can be taken.

As Spring Security depends on Spring Framework, one can look at the dependency tree of  Spring Security to identify the compatible version of Spring Framework.

Now this can take some iterations but in the end one would get an accurate result.

Refer to the compile dependencies section in the [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/4.2.13.RELEASE) page